# Navigating to XAML page from WebView Windows Store application

Tags: webview, navigation, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am developing an application, where I need to open a full-screen WebView over my existing XAML page.

Now I've added a AppBar over this WebView. The requirement is that, appBar button click should navigate me to different application Page.

e.g. WebView is opened on MainPage.xaml and on clicking the AppBar button added on this webView I have to navigate to SeconsPage.XAML

I am not able to do this now and seeing an exception thrown by COntrol_webview,exe

Can I do such navigation? If Yes, pleas help me to find out what I am I missing?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It should work just fine. What exception are you seeing? A problem you might see with the AppBar once you fix the problem with your exception is that it will not render over the WebView control and you need to use a WebViewBrush and hide the WebView when the AppBar is shown. This is called an airspace issue since a WebView is technically a window overlaid on top of the other "Jupiter window" used to render your XAML. Also to enable showing it with mouse you might need to either hook up the right click inside of a WebView or perhaps leave a 1px margin around the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

go for a native app - it saves you a lot of trouble. Filip Skakun already described the first crazy thing about the webview (with the webviewbrush).

if not, you can use the script notification to communicate back and forth between your webapp and your store app. here's a good link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx